# Mercurial alternative to the following git log command

Tags: git, mercurial

I wonder if there's a compatible alternative to the following git log command in Mercurial:

> git log --pretty=oneline --parents --name-only --reverse

Thanks.

Comment: Please show the output from Git, just in case someone has Mercurial but not Git.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working with the following command:

```
log --debug -r : --style my.style
```

Contents of the my.style:

```
changeset = "{node} {parents} {desc|firstline}\n{files}\n"
file  = "{file}\n"
parent = "{node} "
```

The output would be almost identical to the git command that I posted with the one exception: there will be one odd whitespace after

Answer (score 3):

This is as close as I got with `--template`:

> $ hg log --template "{rev}:{node|short} {parents}{desc|firstline}\n{files}\n"

Which produces:

```
15047:8050db40bc5a 15045:7f504202cb5c ui: pass ' ' to raw_input when prompting
mercurial/ui.py
15046:c019df62de45 15043:0bb0f807dfc3 15045:7f504202cb5c merge with stable
mercurial/commands.py mercurial/help/config.txt
15045:7f504202cb5c help/config: strip trailing whitespace
mercurial/help/config.txt
```

Using a [style file](http://selenic.com/repo/hg/file/86380f24e697/mercurial/templates/map-cmdline.default), you can customize the way `parents` is printed to be the full hash and change the delimiter of `files` to a new line.

Comment: Your solution generates output that's pretty different from the original git log version. Thanks nonetheless.